"Error building Player because scripts had compiler errors" y otro error en el binlog al exportar proyecto en Unity
Intento exportar mi proyecto de Unity 2D, sin embargo, la consola me marca que ocurren dos errores:
-Problemas en los script del Player
-Problemas al exportar el proyecto. Me marca que se construyó correctamente pero como fallido
El Player no solo cuneta con su script, sino también cuneta con colisionadores que controlan misiones, pero he revisado cada uno y no hay errores

